# Stopping 404 pages when adding get variable to the URL

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have a Drupal 8 website with a URL like http://mywebsite.com/my-content-url/my-content-url. What I have done is adding a variable to the URL, making it like http://mywebsite.com/my-content-url/my-content-url/myvariable.

How do I get Drupal 8 to stop seeing /myvariable as a part of the URL and giving me a 404 error?

Answer (score 2):

You need a menu callback that accepts the variable. For more info, take a look at the [Drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1800686).

Another way to do this is to pass your variable as a query parameter like http://mywebsite.com/my-content-url/my-content-url?var=myvariable. You can then use code to parse that parameter from the URL. You can get those parameters by using something like `\Drupal::request()->query->all();`

Comment: Thanks, I need the first one.  So do I add it in my template.theme or do I need to create small module for this?

Comment: The correct way to do this is in a module.